# Print elements of array of arrays of different size in same line in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, printing, arrayofarrays

Maybe someone could help me with this. I have an array of arrays. The internal arrays have different sizes (from 2 to 4 elements).

```
letters = [["A", "B"],["C", "D", "F", "G"],["H", "I", "J" ]]
```

I'm trying to print in a same line each array havins as first column element[0] and element[1] joined, as 2nd column element[0], element[1], element[2] joined as 3rd column element[0], element[1], element[3] joined. Elements 2 and 3 not always exist.

The output I'm trying to get is like this:

```
AB
CD CDF CDG
HI HIJ
```

I'm doing in this way but I'm getting this error.

```
letters.map{|x| puts x[0]+x[1] + "," + x[0]+x[1]+x[2] + "," + x[0]+x[1]+x[3]}
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
        from (irb):1915:in "+"
        from (irb):1915:in "block in irb_binding"
        from (irb):1915:in "map"
        from (irb):1915
        from /usr/bin/irb:11:in "<main>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
letters.each do |a,b,*rest|
  puts rest.each_with_object([a+b]) { |s,arr| arr << arr.first + s }.join(' ')
end
```

prints

```
AB
CD CDF CDG
HI HIJ
```

The steps are as follows.

Suppose

```
letters =  [["C", "D", "F", "G"],["H", "I", "J" ]]
```

Then

```
enum0 = letters.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["C", "D", "F", "G"], ["H", "I", "J"]]:each>
```

The first element of this enumerator is generated and passed to the block, and the three block variables are assigned values.

```
a, b, *rest = enum0.next
  #=> ["C", "D", "F", "G"]
a
  #=> "C"
b 
  #=> "D"
rest
  #=> ["F", "G"]
```

Next, we obtain

```
enum1 = rest.each_with_object([a+b])
  #=> rest.each_with_object(["CD"]) 
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["F", "G"]:each_with_object(["CD"])>
```

The first element of this enumerator is generated and passed to the block, and the block variables are assigned values.

```
s, arr = enum1.next
  #=> ["F", ["CD"]]
s
  #=> "F"
arr
  #=> ["CD"]
```

The block calculation is now performed.

```
arr << arr.first + s
  #=> arr << "CD" + "F"
  #=> ["CD", "CDF"]
```

The second and last element of `enum1` is generated and passed to the block, and block variables are assigned values and the block is computed.

```
s, arr = enum1.next
  #=> ["G", ["CD", "CDF"]]
arr << arr.first + s
  #=> ["CD", "CDF", "CDG"]
```

When an attempt to generate another element from `enum1` we obtain

```
enum1.next
  #StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

Ruby handles the exception by breaking out of the block and returning `arr`. The elements of `arr` are then joined:

```
arr.join(' ')
  #=> "CD CDF CDG"
```

and printed.

The second and last element of `enum0` is now generated, passed to the block, and the three block variables are assigned values.

```
a, b, *rest = enum0.next
  #=> ["H", "I", "J"]
a
  #=> "H"
b
  #=> "I"
rest
  #=> ["J"]
```

The remaining calculations are similar.

Some readers may be unfamiliar with the method [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), which is widely used. Read the doc, but note that here it yields the same result as the code written as follows.

```
letters.each do |a,b,*rest|
  arr = [a+b]
  rest.each { |s| arr << arr.first + s }
  puts arr.join(' ')
end
```

By using `each_with_object` we avoid the need for the statement `arr = [a+b]` and the statement `puts arr.join(' ')`. The functions of those two statements are of course there in the line using `each_with_object`, but most Ruby users prefer the flow when when *chaining* `each_with_object` to `join(' ')`. One other difference is that the value of `arr` is confined to `each_with_object`'s block, which is good programming practice.

Comment: Thanks Cary Swoveland, it works pretty fine. It´s kind of difficult for me to understand the logic. If have a chance and time I´ll appreciate if you could explain how it works.

Comment: Suspeg, I've provided the explanation you requested. If you are new to Ruby it deserves careful study.

Comment: Very appreciated Cary Swoveland. Thanks for detailed explanation. Yes, I'm new to ruby and read your step by step. I confess I still have a pending porcentage of these steps to be fully understood by me but is very useful for all that see it.

Comment: Suspeg, I added a bit more explanation at the end of my answer.

Comment: I had issues to understand `each_with_object`, with your explanation I understanf better the logic and why you use it. Thanks for help you give share you knowdledge with others, really

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to join the first two letters, then take the cartesian product with the remaining.

```
letters.each do |arr|
   first = arr.take(2).join
   rest = arr.drop(2)
   puts [first, [first].product(rest).map(&:join)].join(" ")
end
```

This provides the exact output you specified.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks so much for the help. It works perfect. Nice to learn new things in practice like take and drop. Besides that how is named this kind of expressions inside map `(&:join)` and how it works?

Comment: `map(&:join)` is shorthand for `map{|x| x.join}`.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, `Enumerable#map`-only solution.

```
letters = [["A", "B"],["C", "D", "F", "G"],["H", "I", "J" ]]

letters.map do |f, s, *rest|
  rest.unshift(nil).map { |l| [f, s, l].join }.join(' ')
end.each(&method(:puts))

#⇒ AB
#  CD CDF CDG
#  HI HIJ
```

Comment: mudasobwa Thanks, thanks, very appreciated to receive another way to solve this issue. It helps to learn.